# Can I add a template preprocessor that's more specific than an existing hook?

Tags: hooks, theming

I have a preprocessor function in my model that runs on the views_view_table hook. I want it to be called only for a specific view. If it were a hook, rather than a preprocessor, I could use, for example views_view_table__myview. Can I do that with just the preprocessor, too, or do I have to register a matching hook? If so, how do I make sure it does exactly what the base hook does?

Comment: No hook is called `view_table`, so it's difficult to understand your question. Anyway, no Views hook is named after the views created, so you have to test the view object properties to know what view a hook is executing on.

Answer (score 0):

For the Views module, if you want to know its template file suggestions:

- Open edit for your view
- Click on 'Theme information'
- Use whichever template name that meets requirements
- Go back to your view and, at the bottom of 'Theme information', click 'Rescan template files'
- Your template file should be highlighted in this list